# Записать список в файл

Tags: python, json, классы, list

Я пытаюсь записать список в файл с расширением json.
У меня это получается, но потом мне нужно добавить в список элемент и перезаписать файл
Выдает ошибку NameError: name 'path' is not defined, я не понимаю в чем проблема

```
 import json
    class PersistentList:
        def __init__(self, iterable, path):
            self._iterable= iterable
            self.path = path
            with open (path,'w') as file:
                json.dump(iterable,file)
            
        def append(self,item):
            self._item=item
            self._iterable.append (self._item)
            with open (path,'w') as file:
                json.dump(self._iterable,file)
                
        def __getitem__(self, item):
            pass
        def __delitem__(self, key):
            pass
        def __repr__(self):
            pass
    spisok = PersistentList([1,2,3],'file.json')
    spisok.append([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: обычная невнимательность, в методе `append` вместо `path` надо `self.path`. Но у Вас должно записаться [1,2,3,[1,2,3]] если Вы к этому стремились то все ок)

Comment: А если список всё же не должен быть вложенным, то при добавлении списка в список используйте `.extend`, а не `.append`